# Why Blender has no Cycles render built in?

Tags: blender

There is no Cycles Render in Blender. And there is no OpenCL and CUDA acceleration support.
Please improve this and update the repositary (Blender 2.63)

Comment: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.61/Cycles claims blender has cycles rendering. But you should ask these question on the blender community page. http://www.blender.org/community/user-community/ AskUbuntu.com can not help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug report or feature request, please report it at the correct location as AskUbuntu is not a bug tracker or feature request system.